# JUnit5 run tests by tags

Tags: maven, selenium, annotations, tags, junit5

I have a setup Maven+JUnit5+Selenium, my `pom.xml` https://github.com/13Dima13/G/blob/master/pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <properties>
                    <includeTags>${tag}</includeTags>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-logger-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire-logger-api}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

First i thought that `@Tag` works fine, because when i put an annotation to my class https://github.com/13Dima13/G/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/project/TestThreads2.java

```
@Test
@Tag("smoke")
public void test1() {
    open("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17");
    $("#maincontent > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th").waitUntil(Condition.appears, 120000);
    $("#maincontent > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th").shouldBe(Condition.text("License"));
    assertEquals("Maven Repository: log4j » log4j » 1.2.17", title());
    out.println("test1 Passed");
}
```

and then ran from terminal

```
mvn test -Dtag=smoke
```

it executed only the tests which were marked as `@Tag("smoke")`, so in my case only one test and this made me happy.

**But** 
when I started to use it on my real project I realized that it does not work sometimes.

For example, if my `Test.class` with tests methods is not placed in the parent project folder (for example inside child of project folder) https://github.com/13Dima13/G/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/project/test2/GoogleSearch.java, annotation will not work at all.

So annotation `@Tag` doesn't work for the whole project or did I miss something?

Good example https://ibb.co/gjbSZJ

Answer (score 1):

First guess: The name of your test class (`test3.java`) does not match maven‘s default pattern for test classes and it will therefore be ignored.

Comment: For example, I have absolutely fine class and method https://github.com/13Dima13/G/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/project/test2/GoogleSearch.java But anyway framework will not find tag... Look at the picture: 
https://ibb.co/gjbSZJ

Comment: Well, „GoogleSearch“ is outside Maven‘s default naming pattern. BTW, does IntelliJ run the test when you use a configuration with Test kind = Tags?

Answer (score 1):

Give

`mvn test -D groups=smoke`

a try...

Or, if you like to see results pretty fast (and don't need to have your code recompiled), go for:

`mvn surefire:test -D groups=smoke`

Note that the space after `-D` is optional and purely for cosmetic reasons.

> *N.B. i am also rather new to the java/maven world, but for what it's worth: i never got it to work with `-D tag` in the first place so far. Would love to know what's up with that (comments linking to an explanation?)*

Answer (score 0):

The support of JUnit 5 is contained in [Maven Surefire Plugin Version 2.22.0](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html)

```
<dependencies>
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    [...]
</dependencies>
```

and maybe you need to define maven-surefire-plugin like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>some test to exclude here</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So your configuration can be simplified.